# how to speed up cross_val_score?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want to evaluate a SGDClassifier on MNIST Dataset using `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score`.
It took me about 6 minute on 3-fold.
How can i speed up the process using full system power (i mean use everything from CPU to graphic card and etc.)
By the way i was monitoring CPU usage, it only used 54% of its power.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784')
X, y = mnist['data'], mnist['target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]
y_train_5 = (y_train == 5)
y_test_5 = (y_test == 5)

sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

cross_val_score(sgd_clf, X_train, y_train, cv=3, scoring='accuracy')
```

Comment: try putting `n_jobs=x`  where `x>1` inside `cross_val_score`. Not sure if it'll work though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html):

> **n_jobs : *int or None, optional (default=None)***
>
> The number of CPUs to use to do the computation. None means 1 unless in a joblib.parallel_backend context. -1 means using all processors.

i.e. you can use all your available cores with

```
cross_val_score(sgd_clf, X_train, y_train, cv=3, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1)
```

or specify some other value `n_jobs=k`, if using all the cores makes your machine slow or unresponsive.

This will employ more CPU cores; as far as I know, there is no functionality in scikit-learn to offload computations to the GPU.

Comment: do you know if sklearn shares dataset among worker processes or copies it for each of them? otherwise this might lead to memory error

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan I guess it shares but not sure, you'd better check and see how it goes